# How to use a multiple timeframe for each indicator in one script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

indicator(title='Scalp BTC M5', timeframe="5")

**First indicator : ZLSMA**

```
length = input(title='Length', defval=50)
offset = input(title='Offset', defval=0)

src = input(close, title='Source')
lsma = ta.linreg(src, length, offset)
lsma2 = ta.linreg(lsma, length, offset)
eq = lsma - lsma2
zlsma = lsma + eq

plot(zlsma, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), linewidth=3)
```

**Second indicator : AO**

```
ao_fast = input(5, 'AO Fast EMA Lenth')
ao_slow = input(34, 'AO Slow EMA Length')

ao = ta.ema(hl2, ao_fast) - ta.ema(hl2, ao_slow)

color_ao = ta.change(ao) > 0 ? #115500 : #992211
plot(ao, style=plot.style_columns, color=color_ao, transp=0)
```

**Third indicator : HVI**

```
len = input(10)

HV = ta.highest(volume, len)
HVI = volume * 100 / HV[1]
plot(HVI, color=color.new(color.black, 0), title='HVI')
band1 = hline(100)
band0 = hline(50)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.new(color.purple, 90))
```

Thus, the first indicator should be in 15' minutes and the others in
5' minutes. The reading of the indicator will be in 5' minutes on the
graph.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function on each of those indicators.

For example, to get the `ZLSMA` from the 15 min timeframe:

```
zlsma_15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", zlsma)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering, I did that for each of indicators but zlsma still stay in 5 minutes, you know why ?

Comment: Sorry, it's worked, thank you boss.